# azure logic app & http step response

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

I have 2 HTTP actions, one after another in a logic app, how do I read the response from a previous HTTP action in the second HTTP action?

First HTTP call (REST) returns a response in JSON format -

```
{

   "authResult": {

      "isPasswordExpired": true,

      "authToken": "cxxcxcxc",

      "message": "Login Successful"
   }
}
```

I want to send `authtoken` from the result in second http action as authorization header.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.

1. Use expression to directly reference the property. `@body('NameOfFirstHTTPAction')?['authResult']?'[authToken]`
2. Add a "Parse JSON" action in between the two HTTP action, and provide a sample response of the first HTTP action to generate a schema. Then, in the second HTTP action, you will see `authToken` as a token from the dynamic content picker for you to reference.

Answer (score 14):

As Derke Li mentioned that we could use exression or  Parse Json to do that. I also do a demo about how to use the Parse JSON action.

1.Add the Parse Json action after the first Http action

[image]

2.Add the parse content and click on the button "Use sample payload to generate schema" and that will pop a new window. Paste in your "authResult" json. As seen in the below image.

[image]

3.Then we could pick the token from the dynamic content.

[image]

4.We could check the result.
[image]